# Control Search Parameters in PHP Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, search, query-string

Search parameters are null in PHP Wordpress

When user press search button, it make query string parameters even if search fields are empty

> www.example.com/?ssc=&sst=&s=

How i can check it and remove (Don't Allow) null parameters from url

Comment: Why don't you use HTML5 required validation

Comment: how i can use it ? explain more please

Answer (score 0):

If you know where your form is situated, add required to input text

```
<input type="text" name="s" id="search" value="<?php the_search_query(); ?>" required />
```

or else create `searchform.php` in your theme directory and add following code

```
<form action="/" method="get">
    <label for="search">Search in <?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?></label>
    <input type="text" name="s" id="search" value="<?php the_search_query(); ?>" required  />
    <input type="image" alt="Search" src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' ); ?>/images/search.png" />
</form>
```